# Django Test Client Like Tool?

Tags: python, django, testing

I've got to know and love the Django Test client.  I'd really like to use it to test external sites and URLs outside of the current project.

- Is this possible?
- If not, is there something similar I could use? (ideally in Python)

I don't need to do anything dramatic, just, say, grab a URL and check the status code, check that it took less than x seconds, and that it contains some text.

Ideally I'd like it so that I could run/trigger these tests from some sort of hosted web app, and also have them run at certain intervals.

I realise it wouldn't take too much to roll something myself, but I'd prefer to jump onboard something which already exists so wanted to check what the options were before I do so.

Thanks loads.

Rolo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't work like that. It's not a real web client, it's just a piece of internal Django code that catches the request and returns the relevant response.

The best tool for the sort of testing you're talking about is something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).